# VBA code to get the occurrence index of the text for a excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel column containing text values. The values can repeat any number of times in a column. for example here is my column.

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
BBBB
EEEE
FFFF
BBBB
CCCC
CCCC
DDDD
```

I need 2 VBA codes which will work as follows:

**Code1:** this code will return the number of times the cell text has appeared until the current cell. for example, if the current cell is the 9th row, then the output will be 3, because CCCC has appeared 3 times till that cell.

**Code2:** this code will return the row ID of the n'th occurrence of the text. for example, I want the row number of 2nd appearance of BBBB, so the output will be 4

Can anyone please help with the codes? thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Both can be achieved via formulas. Are you sure you still want VBA?

Comment: Easy enough -- what have you tried?

Comment: +1 to @SiddharthRout COUNTIF with ROW functions together with dynamically changing range will do the job smoothly. But in terms of practice VBA is still an option))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill down from cell B1 with the formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)` and it will give you count up to that cell.

Second part can be achieved so many ways, but try this overly-verbose approach and adjust to your needs:

After using suggsetiong for column B above, cell C1: `=A1&B1` and fill down

Cell D1: Fill down from 1 to bottom of list

Cell G1:??1 copy-paste(transpose) the unique text strings
Cell F2: Fill down from 1 to n
Cell G2: `=INDEX($D$1:$D$17,MATCH(G$1&$F2,$C$1:$C$17,0))` and then copy this down and right to fill the square.